# field method doesnt work in let with several sub-blocks

Tags: java, clojure

I got this piece of java code from the net

```
import java.util.zip.CRC32;

public static short getCRC(String s, int i, byte bytes[])
{
      CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
      if (s != null)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
          {
              char c = s.charAt(j);
              crc32.update(c);
          }
      }
      crc32.update(i);
      crc32.update(i >> 8);
      crc32.update(i >> 16);
      crc32.update(i >> 24);
      for (int k = 0; k < bytes.length; k++)
      {
          byte byte0 = bytes[k];
          crc32.update(byte0);
      }
      return (short) (int) crc32.getValue();
}
```

and I tried to translate it to Clojure:

```
(defn getCRC [s i bytes]
    (let [crc32 (CRC32.)]
        (if (not= s nil)
            (for [c s] (.update crc32 (int c)))
        )
        (map #(.update crc32 (int (bit-shift-right i %))) [0 8 16 24])
        (for [c bytes]
            (.update crc32 (int c))
        )
        (.getValue crc32)
    )
)
```

but it seems the `.update` doesn't work and function returns 0.
I evaluated every block in the `let` body and it works fine.
I also put another `.update` before the `.getValue` with a numerical and it works fine and the return value of function becomes the CRC32 of it;
but when I bundle them together the return value becomes 0 again.

any help or idea are greatly appreciated!

Comment: and i'm using clojure-1.6.jar REPL

Comment: try (dorun (map ...))

Comment: @edbond I tried it but when I enter this into the REPL it gives away a crc checksum but when I call the function(no matter with what arguments) it returns 0

Comment: see http://rosettacode.org/wiki/CRC-32#Clojure

Comment: and https://github.com/henrygarner/biscuit

Comment: thanks man, for those useful links... but this code is a special form of CRC for a keygen program written in java and i just wanted to learn clojure by translating it. tutorials work better ;)

Comment: that's great, here is another link for you. Read how to format clojure - https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide

Comment: @edbond I never really understood lispers' love for series of closing parens. Especially taken into account how often I see them looking for the missing/extra one on presentations etc.. The style OP uses isn't really half bad. Closing paren either on the same line or alone at the same level of indentation as the opening one. Doesn't even need a whole github page to explain that :) The only good reason to use the "official" one IMO is the inertia it already has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that both [`for`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for) and [`map`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map) yield lazy sequences.

Since you don't force their results anywhere in your code the sequence isn't realized and the calls to `.update` are never made.

Try subtituting both for [`doseq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doseq) -  an iteration form that deals specifically with side-effects (among other things isn't lazy) and see how that changes the result:

```
(defn getCRC [s i bytes]
    (let [crc32 (CRC32.)]
        (if (not= s nil)
            (doseq [c s] (.update crc32 (int c)))
        )
        (doseq [x [0 8 16 24]] (.update crc32 (int (bit-shift-right i x))))
        (doseq [c bytes]
            (.update crc32 (int c))
        )
        (.getValue crc32)
    )
)
```